# displaying the different image

Tags: android, image

I am creating an application in which i have a text box which is giving the description of the image.and on touch it will describe position of image.in the lower side i have used two button for navigating between image.what should i do for this ? I am not understanding that thing .

I have used the image in the other class then i call that image but it is not working . i ma stuck in this from three days can any one help me on this .

If any one think that i am re asking this question then i am sorry.

[image: image i want this way]
my code is as follow of first image

```
public class FirstImage extends ImageView {
    float a=0;
    float b=0;

    TextView t= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    public FirstImage(Context context) {
        super(context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

    }

    public FirstImage(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
          super(context, attrs);

    }




    public  boolean onTouch(MotionEvent me){
        switch(me.getAction()){
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            a=me.getX();
            b= me.getY();
            pageinfo(a,b);
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            a=me.getX();
            b= me.getY();
            pageinfo(a,b);
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            a=me.getX();
            b= me.getY();
            pageinfo(a,b);
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE:
            a=me.getX();
            b= me.getY();
            pageinfo(a,b);
            break;
        default: return false;
        }
        return true;

    }

   public void pageinfo(float a,float b){

        t.setText(Float.toString(a)+"x"+Float.toString(b)+"y");

    }



}
```

I have call in the layout file as follow...

```
<com.example.androidtablayout.FirstImage
         android:id="@+id/myandroid"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent"
         android:src="@drawable/human"
         />
```

but i am not understanding why it is not showing any thing ontouch event.

Comment: You should share your relevant code (activity sources, layouts), for a better understanding of the problem. Also the Logcat output of any exception would be helpful.

Comment: please follow this qustion http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10577848/displaying-image-from-other-class-in-android

Comment: I have a hard time understanding what you're trying to achieve and where you're stuck. Can you better explain what you're doing (code, screenshots, text), what you would expect to happen and what happens instead. Instead of "it is not working" you should tell us whether it throws an exception, does not compile, shows unexpected elements in the user interface, freezes etc.

Comment: @codo i have edited my qustion now you  can see the image how i want that application.

Comment: is this an imageview? change the resource source? (i.e. setSomethingSomething)

Comment: @keyser i have used it the image view initial but when i will implement the image touch for the each image then i have to use the class for the each image.then it is showing me the error as null pointer exception or unable to start activity.

Comment: If you get a nullpointer, locate the null object and fix it (using debugging)

Answer (score 0):

The following code (in the `VideosActivity` class, taken from the linked question) is the problem:

```
FirstImage  i= new FirstImage (this);
```

It creates a *FirstImage* instance in the implicitly created constructor of your class. But you cannot generate a UI widget so early in the activity's life cycle. And you don't need to either because the layout inflater will generated all UI widgets for your.

So just change the code to:

```
FirstImage  i;
```

That should do.

The correct way to initialize the instance variable `i` is already in your code, namely to call `findViewById()` in `onCreate()`.

**Update:**

It seems that you expect `onTouch` to be called when the image is touched. But `onTouch` isn't a method of the superclass that you could override. Instead, `onTouch` is the method of the `View.OnTouchListener` interface.

To fix it, either register the instance as a listener (using `setOnTouchListener`) and declare it to implement `View.OnTouchListener`. Or change the method name to `OnTouchEvent` (which can be overridden).

Comment: If it throws an exception as well, then it's a different exception or at least an exception with a different stacktrace. Please post the full stracktrace and don't have us guess.

Comment: now i just solve that thing but now when i am touching the image it is not displaying any thing .you can check my code . i have edited it in my question.